# How do I make a function to validate the input of the user and link it to my CRUD php file?

Tags: php, html

I tried learning Regex. Now, I am trying to create a function to validate the user inputs but unsure how to implement to PHP. Please help

```
**This is my Validation php**

<?php


function validateInput($userID, $userName, $userContact, $userEmail, $userDOB)
{
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1-10}$/", $userID)) //checks for userID
        {
            echo "Only Numbers and letters allowed in ID Field";
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-z\s]{1-10}$/", $userName)) //checks for User Name
        {
            echo "Only letters and spaces allowed in Name Field";
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]{8}$/", $userContact)) //checks for User Contact
        {
            echo "Only numbers allowed in Contact Field";
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/\w+@\w+.\w+/", $userEmail)) //checks for User Email
        {
            echo "Invalid Email Format";
        }
        else if(!preg_match("/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/", $userDOB)){ //checks for user Date of Birth
            echo"Invalid Date Format";
        }
}
```

**This is the CRUD.php file. I want to link it the validation.php function here. How do I do it?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db5c3af"); if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno()); } include "q4.php";

$actiontype = $_POST["actiontype"]; $add = $actiontype === "Add"; //boolean type comparator to check actiontype value === checks value + type $update = $actiontype === "Update"; $delete = $actiontype === "Delete";
```

> The problem lies here but I am unsure how to do.

```
if($actiontype!= "List All"){
    $userID = $_POST["userID"];
    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    $userContact = $_POST["userContact"];
    $userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
    $userDOB = $_POST["userDOB"];
    $check = validateInput($userID, $userName, $userContact, $userEmail, $userDOB);
    if($check==false){
        ;
    } }


if ($add || $update || $delete) { //Read in the form data assign to variables

    $userID = $_POST["userID"];
    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
    $userContact = $_POST["userContact"];
    $userEmail = $_POST["userEmail"];
    $userDOB = $_POST["userDOB"];



    if ($add) {
        $query = $con->prepare("Insert into ItemA4491209 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");
        $query->bind_param('ssiss', $userID, $userName, $userContact, $userEmail, $userDOB);
    }

$con->close();
```

Comment: What is your specific problem? Does this code not work?

Comment: I have updated it

Comment: Having one giant validator function isn't wrong, but it doesn't scale well, which may or may not be a problem for you. But, the way you are using it, it appears you are missing a `return` in the function, `true` on success and `false` on failure. There's no right or wrong way, but for this kind of setup I'd personally have the function return an error message when applicable, or null-ish on success. Then you'd do `if($msg = validateInput(...)){echo $msg;}`

Comment: where do I put the true and false?

Comment: This depends on what you want the function to do. Should it return the first error message that it encounters? If so, you can replace all `echo`s with `return`s (and also remove the `else`). If you want to return all errors, you probably want to collect it into an array, and either return an empty array and check for that, or return null if it is empty.

Comment: I would like the function to check each input fields.

Comment: Ignoring RegEx, forms and databases for a moment, are you comfortable writing regular PHP code? I apologize if asking that is offensive, I do not intend that to be.

Comment: I am not that comfortable yet

Comment: My recommendation would be to find some beginner tutorials for PHP, and just get the basics down, functions, control flow (`if`, `while`, etc.), general variables. Then, if you want to, maybe OOP concepts such as `namespace` and `class`. That part isn't required for PHP, but a lot of modern code uses it so it is good to be familiar with it at least. I'd then get some basics of HTML, if you aren't familiar already. At this point I'd start mixing in RegEx. Then, after all that, I'd move on to databases. Unfortunately I don't have a specific tutorial to recommend.